# How to download an xlsx file when using the Reports REST API

Tags: apex, excel

I'm looking for ways that I can download the results of reports **in Apex** and save them as Salesforce Files in either CSV or Excel format.

I came across [this page from the Salesforce Reports REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_download_excel.htm), which explains how to get the API to return the report as an Excel file.

I'm sure this works when calling the api from a browser, but I am calling this API from Apex code and would like to get at the file that is specified in the Content-Disposition header of the response. But, I when create a Salesforce File (ContentVersion) using the results of `response.getBody()`, then I am unable to open the created file, presumably because it is corrupted. I'm not what the structure of the response body is. When I print it out, it has all the crazy characters that make me think it is in a binary format.

Is there a way that I can get this data saved in Apex? Or is there a better way to **programmatically** download report data from the server-side in Salesforce?

Here is my code:

```
Http http = new Http();

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(REPORTS_REST_API + reportId);
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

HttpResponse response;

try {

    response = http.send(request);

    ContentWorkspace archivedReportsLibrary = [
            Select Id From ContentWorkspace Where Name = :ARCHIVED_REPORTS_LIBRARY
    ];

    ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
    conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // In Salesforce
    conVer.PathOnClient = fileName;
    conVer.Title = fileName;
    conver.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(response.getBody());
    conver.FirstPublishLocationId = archivedReportsLibrary.Id;
    insert conVer;

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] to share your Apex code? It looks like you are calling the right API but possibly something is wrong in processing the return value.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed . I've added my code.